# How do I conditionally exclude/ include field in fomset on Django admin site TabularInline?

Tags: python, django

`Point System QA` model with `Point System QA details` model rendered as `tabular inline` form. How can I conditionally exclude/include a field from the `Point System QA details` formset?

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Model**

```
class PointSystemQADetails(models.Model):
point_name      = models.ForeignKey('PointSystemQA', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
brand           = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
model           = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
amount          = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
... more filed
```

**Admin page:**

```
# Point System QA Details Formset #
class PointSystemQADetailsFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def get_form_kwargs(self, index):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(index)
        kwargs['parent_object'] = self.instance
        return kwargs
            
class PointSystemQADetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    brand       = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [])
    model       = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [])

    def __init__(self, *args, parent_object, **kwargs):
        self.parent_object = parent_object
        super(PointSystemQADetailsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
               
        if self.parent_object.device_type.id == 19:
            del self.fields['model'] # not working..
            self.fields['brand'].choices = [('', '------'),] + [(x.pk, x.manufacturer_name) for x in Manufacturer.objects.all()]
        else:
            self.fields['brand'].choices = [('', '------'),] + [(x.pk, x.manufacturer_name) for x in Manufacturer.objects.all()]
            self.fields['model'].choices = [('', '------'),] + [(x.pk, x.series) for x in WatchSeries.objects.all()]


class PointSystemQADetailsAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model   = PointSystemQADetails
    formset = PointSystemQADetailsFormSet
    form    = PointSystemQADetailsForm
    extra   = 1
# End Point System #

class PointSystemQAAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PointSystemQA
        exclude = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'created_by', 'updated_by']
    
class PointSystemQAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = PointSystemQA
    inlines = [PointSystemQADetailsAdmin]
    form = PointSystemQAAdminForm
    save_on_top = True
    list_display_links = ('point_name', )
    search_fields = ('point_name', )
    list_display = ['point_name', 'amount', 'device_type', 'is_serialized']
```